# Dropdown menu move elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to make dropdown menu move diagonal if submenu is opened? currently my menu moves up and down as you can see http://jsfiddle.net/LthgY/1280/ 
i would like to add curved picture next to it but since it moves up and down, it crashes into picture

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu > li > a").on("click", function(e){
    if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $("#menu li ul").slideUp(350);
      $("#menu li a").removeClass("open");

      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
      $(this).addClass("open");
    }

    else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure -- you can just rotate your dropdown box with transform

```
#menu { 
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Can be added to your CSS to achieve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/LthgY/1281/

---

**EDIT:** 
 From comment

regarding having the elements remain upright, but "slide down"  diagonally.

You might have to do some fine-tuning but this will illustrate the overall idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/LthgY/1282/

I changed the following CSS rules:

```
 #menu li ul {
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: translateX( -50px);
   transform: translateY(10px);
   display: none;
   line-height: 70%;
  }
```

Essentially what this does is `rotates` the  sub-list within a menu  only and then `translates` (`moves`) the sublist to make up for the position offset caused by the rotational transformation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu > li > a").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $("#menu li ul").slideUp(350);
      $("#menu li a").removeClass("open");

      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
      $(this).addClass("open");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
/* 
 *  modified CSS rule  below
 */

#menu {
  margin-left: 65px;
}
#menu li ul {
  transform: translateX(-90px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-left: -30px;
  display: none;
  line-height: 70%;
}
#menu li ul li {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#menu li ul li a {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
/* end of modified rules */

#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a class="menu1" href="#">Menu1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menu1_1" href="#">A</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_2" href="#">B</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_3" href="#">C</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_4" href="#">D</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="menu2" href="#">Menu2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menu1_1" href="#">A</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_2" href="#">B</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_3" href="#">C</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_4" href="#">D</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="menu3" href="#">Menu3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menu1_1" href="#">A</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_2" href="#">B</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_3" href="#">C</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_4" href="#">D</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="menu4" href="#">Menu4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menu1_1" href="#">A</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_2" href="#">B</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_3" href="#">C</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_4" href="#">D</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="menu5" href="#">Menu5</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menu1_1" href="#">A</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_2" href="#">B</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_3" href="#">C</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_4" href="#">D</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="menu6" href="#">Menu6</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menu1_1" href="#">A</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_2" href="#">B</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_3" href="#">C</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_4" href="#">D</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="menu7" href="#">Menu7</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menu1_1" href="#">A</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_2" href="#">B</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_3" href="#">C</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menu1_4" href="#">D</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE** There are still some cosmetic issues that will need to be addressed such as the letters appearing backwards -- but at least this answer gives you a basic idea of how to do it..

hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking of making it "slide down" to rotate not down but to i.e 45deg so that if you click one menu, other menus move 45 degrees not straight down